# Shopify Liquid - Some tag filtered blogs not showing

Tags: shopify, liquid

I've created a blog section for some pages on a client site which are tagged and filtered via the liquid code.

```
{% for article in blogs.news.articles %}
        {% if template == "page.mountain-biking" %}
{% if article.tags contains 'biking' %}
{% include 'blog-grid-snippet' %}
{% endif %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
```

There are elsif statements for different pages which filter by different tags.
blog-grid snippet is the code to display individual tiles in a grid:

```
<div class="grid__item {{ blog_item_width  }}">
        <div class="article">
          <div class="blog-description">
            <div class="page-blog-content blog-detail" style="background-image:url({{ article | img_url: 'master' }});background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;">
              <a href="{{ article.url }}">
                <div class="button-text">
              <h4>{{ article.title }}</h4>
              <p>Read More ></p>
                </div>
             </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

On one page it shows all the tagged articles correctly, but on the other three it misses 2 or 3 articles for no apparent reason.
Swimming posts have 8 tagged, but only 5 show?
Am i missing something with the filter above that is skipping posts for some reason?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else looking for an answer to this ... I fixed it by adding the paginate liquid code around the for statement:

```
{% paginate blogs.news.articles by 999 %}
 ....
{% endpaginate %}
```